# Laravel - redirect() vs redirect()->route() vs to_route()

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, routes, url-routing

In Laravel 10, let's suppose I have this route in my `web.php` file:

```
Route::get('/whatever', function() {
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'hello from whatever route'
    ]);
})->name('whatever');
```

Now, I want to redirect from the route `/` to the route `/whatever`. I can use three statements that achieve the same results.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('whatever'); // works
    return redirect()->route('whatever'); // works
    return to_route('whatever') // works
});
```

So, what is the difference between them?

Comment: Try with different Routes; `Route::get('/whatever')` uses the same URL as it's name `->name('whatever')`, but if you have more complicated Routes, like `Route::get('/do/something/{with-param}')` with a name like `->name('do-something.with-param')`, you'll see that the methods may not work.

Comment: [to_route](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php) is just a helper function that returns `redirect()->route($route, $parameters, $status, $headers);`, so it's the exact same as your second line. It just looks nicer.

Comment: and ```to_route()``` does the same thing as ```redirect()```, i guess they all does the same thing

Comment: you use ```redirect()->route('whatever');``` when you want to redirects to a named route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is complicated by the fact that the URL address matches the Route Name. Therefore, I will illustrate the difference between the three functions with a new example.

#### Example

```php
Route::get('/path/to/whatever', function() {
    // ...
})->name('example-whatever-name');
```

#### What is a `redirect()` helper

The `redirect()` is a "helper" in Laravel that performs a redirection. There are multiple ways to redirect a user to a new URL. If you provide the first parameter to the redirect function, you don't have to specify the Route Name, instead, you provide the exact URL address.

Upon invocation, it passes the parameter to the `to()` function of the Redirect class, which expects a URL address. Therefore, the original function was `redirect()->to()`, and its abbreviation became the `redirect()` helper when accepting a parameter.

```php
return redirect('/path/to/whatever'); // an alternative to "redirect()->to()"
```

```php
return redirect()->to('/path/to/whatever'); // an alternative to "Redirect::to()"
```

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

return Redirect::to('/path/to/whatever');
```

It is evident that among the three pieces of code, the first one is the most convenient.

- [Creating Redirects](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/redirects#creating-redirects) - Laravel Docs

For a better understanding, it is recommended to review the source code of the framework as well:

- [The source code of `redirect()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6c53284a09b77dc7e958a41fd6da998c68ef997e/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L643) - Laravel Framework GitHub Repository

It is clearly visible what happens when there is a parameter and when there is no parameter.

#### Calling `redirect()` without parameters, interpretation of the `Redirect` class

If no parameter is provided to the `redirect()` function, it returns an instance of the `Redirect` class, where various functions can be called. Examples of such functions include "action", "route", etc. You are interested in the `route()` function.

For this `route()` function, instead of providing a URL address, you need to pass the Route Name as a parameter, and it redirects to the appropriate route based on the route name.

```php
return redirect()->route('example-whatever-name'); // an alternative to "Redirect::route()"
```

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

return Redirect::route('example-whatever-name');
```

It is evident that among the two pieces of code, the first one is the most convenient, but (under the following title) using `to_route()` will be an even better choice.

- [Redirecting To Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/redirects#redirecting-named-routes) - Laravel Docs

#### What is a `to_route()` helper function

- [image: Status: Laravel PR - [9.x] Adds to_route helper] [Laravel PR - [9.x] Adds `to_route` helper](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/40522)

Since Laravel 9.x, the `to_route()` global function has been introduced to the framework. This is nothing more than a shorter alternative to `redirect()->route()`. In most cases, redirecting with the Route Name is much better and more readable than using a URL address. Therefore, it is wasteful to type out `redirect()->route()` for every redirection. With its abbreviated version, your code becomes shorter and perhaps more readable.

```php
return to_route('example-whatever-name'); // an alternative to "redirect()->route()"
```

- [Redirecting To Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/redirects#redirecting-named-routes) - Laravel Docs

For a better understanding, it is recommended to review the source code of the framework as well:

- [The source code of `to_route()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6c53284a09b77dc7e958a41fd6da998c68ef997e/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L889) - Laravel Framework GitHub Repository

#### Extra: more information about `Redirect::class`

The `Redirect` class is what allows us to perform redirections. The previously mentioned `redirect()` "helper" simply declares this class when called without parameters. Or, when called with a parameter, it immediately passes the parameter to the `Redirect::to()` function.

To avoid the use of many use statements, "helper" functions were introduced, such as the mentioned `redirect()`, which circumvents the need for importing and using `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect`.

- [`\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect`](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Redirect.html) - Laravel API Docs